# Find nested property from ember lodash and pick the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, lodash

I am new to javascript.

I would like to check whether the specific nested property is present or not in an array of items, ex)

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c4ec057e21b840001968d31"),
    "status" : "ACTIVE",
    "customerId" : "sample-book",
    "bookInfo" : {
        "bookChunks" : [ 
            {
                "key" : "Name",
                "value" : "test"
            }, 
            {
                "key" : "Surname1",
                "value" : "testtt"
            }, 
            {
                "key" : "user-contact",
                "value" : "sample-value",
                "ContactList" : {
                    "id" : "sample-id",
                    "timeStamp" : "Tue, 20 Sep 2016 07:49:25 +0000",
                    "contacts" : [ 
                        {
                            "id" : "contact-id1",
                            "name" : "Max Muller",
                            "phone_number" : "+XXXXXXX"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "id" : "contact-id2",
                            "name" : "Max Muller",
                            "phone_number" : "+XXXXXXX"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c4ec057e21b840001968d32"),
    "status" : "ACTIVE",
    "customerId" : "sample-book1",
    "bookInfo" : {
        "bookChunks" : [ 
            {
                "key" : "Name",
                "value" : "test"
            }, 
            {
                "key" : "Surname1",
                "value" : "testtt"
            }
        ]
    }
}]
```

Here, I would like to find whether any item has **ContactList** or **contacts** present. If it is present take the item and put it in a separate list.

I am using ember-lodash. Using normal javascript or lodash would be fine for me. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you want `ContactList` or the items which have `ContactList`? Will `bookInfo.bookChunks` have value for every object in the array?

Comment: I would like to write 2-Utility methods one which should return boolean states contactList is present. Another method should return only item with contactList.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). This returns all the objects which have at least one object with `ContactList` property inside `bookInfo.bookChunks` array.

```js
const input=[{"_id":"5c4ec057e21b840001968d31","status":"ACTIVE","customerId":"sample-book","bookInfo":{"bookChunks":[{"key":"Name","value":"test"},{"key":"Surname1","value":"testtt"},{"key":"user-contact","value":"sample-value","ContactList":{"id":"sample-id","timeStamp":"Tue, 20 Sep 2016 07:49:25 +0000","contacts":[{"id":"contact-id1","name":"Max Muller","phone_number":"+XXXXXXX"},{"id":"contact-id2","name":"Max Muller","phone_number":"+XXXXXXX"}]}}]}},{"_id":"5c4ec057e21b840001968d32","status":"ACTIVE","customerId":"sample-book1","bookInfo":{"bookChunks":[{"key":"Name","value":"test"},{"key":"Surname1","value":"testtt"}]}}]

const output = input.filter(o => 
  o.bookInfo.bookChunks.some(c => "ContactList" in c)
)

console.log(output)
```

If you just want to check if any of the objects have `ContactList`, you could replace `filter` with another `some`

(Note: This assumes that `bookInfo.bookChunks` will not be undefined. Otherwise you'd have to add a undefined check before using the nested property)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt help...How to return boolean if the value is present?

Comment: @VelNaga I have added that in the answer. Replace `input.filter` with `input.some`